# Fixed background issue on Firefox and Safari for mobile

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, safari, parallax

The `background-attachment:fixed` is working well on Chrome but on safari, it does not work. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

for fixing background image please use width and height css element and make sure background-image property use properly.